# Change Particle System's curve via script

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I want to change the curve property of

```
particleSystem.main.startLifetime
```

If I write

```
particleSystem.main.startLifetime = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve();
```

it says

> Cannot modify the return value of 'ParticleSystem.main' because it is not a variable

If I try this

```
particleSystem.main.startLifetime.curve = minCurve;
```

it says

> Cannot modify the return value of 'ParticleSystem.MainModule.startLifetime' because it is not a variable

And if I try to change the curve directly

```
    foreach (var key in minCurve.keys)
    {
        Debug.Log("adding a key");
        particleSystem.main.startLifetime.curve.AddKey(key);
        Debug.Log("length: " + particleSystem.main.startLifetime.curve.keys.Length);
    }
```

It doesn't change the curve at all. The Length is the same, and in the window the curve doesn't change too.

So what do I do wrong?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this thread ? https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cant-set-any-new-particle-system-properties-through-script.358964/

Comment: Yeah, particleSystem.startLifetime returns only float value and marked as deprecated

Comment: Check the duplicated question. Let me know if there is a question.

Comment: Okay, I can change curves of properties that aren't in the main module of ParticleSystem. But ParticleSystem.main.startLifetime is still unchangeable. Though I can get its value.

Comment: oh I see, at first i must main module, thanx